# Xray for Jira Jenkins NUnit test results import task

Tags: jenkins, jira, jira-xray

Hi my Import job with Jenkins is failing with below error . I'm trying to import .xml from Slave machine. I can able to see .xml file in slave location but still getting the error for file not found . when we run the test from Master then it can able to search the xml . so can anyone help with this ?

```
ERROR: File path is a directory or the file doesn't exist
ERROR: Step ‘Xray: Results Import Task’ aborted due to exception: 
java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: File path is a directory or the 
file doesn't exist
at
```

Looks like it is not able to findthe xml file. when i try to import same file using Curl command it is working . can any one help to solve it ?
I'm converting my Nunit xml to nunit2 for my HTML reporting . I tried to import nunit 2 converted xml  manually and works fine but from Jenkins keep on getting error .

Answer (score -1):

If you are able to add plugins to your Jenkins server, there is a plugin specifically to do this, but you won't find it on the Jenkins plugin manager, follow the steps here to install and configure;

[Xray for JIRA Jenkins Plugin](https://confluence.xpand-addons.com/display/XRAY/Xray+for+JIRA+Jenkins+Plugin#XrayforJIRAJenkinsPlugin-Installation)

In short;

1. Download this [xray-for-jira-connector.hpi](https://confluence.xpand-addons.com/download/attachments/21761054/xray-for-jira-connector.hpi?version=2&modificationDate=1502478304519&api=v2)
2. Go to the Update Center of Jenkins ("Manage Jenkins" > "Manage Plugins")
3. Select the advanced tab
4. On the Upload Plugin section, click upload and select the file xray-for-jira-connector.hpi file.
5. Next you need to add your JIRA server configuration to Jenkins (Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Xray for JIRA configuration).

Once you have done the above, you should now be able to add a build step that can export Cucumber feature files from any Cucumber tests you have set up within Xray, and, a post-build action for importing test results files including an NUnit XML file.

All of the info here is described in more detail in the first link i provided, as well as additional information on how to setup the build step and post build action. Hope this helps.

Comment: The Jenkins plugin is now available in the official Jenkins plugin repository, so it can be installed directly from within Jenkins=>manage plugins section.
It also supports importing results from Jenkins slaves; perhaps you were using an old version of the plugin that didn't have support for it.